# How to Set Recycler View Height Dynamically Using wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a fragment containing a recycler view which is populated using data fetched from a server. This fragment is inside a `FragmentContainerView` within the activity. I want the height of the recyclerView to be dynamic. Essentially using `wrap_content` as the height parameter, but when I do that the recyclerView has a height of 0 and doesn't show up at all.

Why doesn't `wrap_content` dynamically adjust the height for my `fragmentContainerView` height?

Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/calendarRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.DashboardActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="com.yambo.yates.fragments.WorkoutCalendarFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/workout_calendar_fragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Dynamically`? Is it programmatically or you mean to have a dynamic height that varies according to the contents?

Comment: No. I want to update the contents of the recyclerview and have `fragmentContainerView`s height update automatically

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerViews already dynamically adjust height based on contents. So as long as your XML is at least wrap_content it should display everything. Are you sure your data is valid?

Also, if your fragment only contains the RecyclerView you can remove the parent ConstraintLayout and change your XML to:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendarRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: There will be additional views inside the fragment, I just  simplified it for the question! And yes the data is valid. If I pin the `FragmentContainerView` to the 4 sides, the recycler view is shown and populates after the network call completes. But with the current code in my question it is "flat" and never has any height

Comment: Well, I tried using your XML in a simple project and was able to see list items. So unless you share your actual code and XML it's unlikely I or anyone else can help you further.